# Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree - The key [LabeledGlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>#ab7de] was used by multiple widgets

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, key, flutter-getx

I am creating TabBar using Getx but getting the error Duplicate GlobalKey detected in the widget tree. So whenever I am going to the second Tab app doesn't show any content. How I solve the issue whenever I am using stateful widget it works but whenever trying Getx to create the TabBar using the stateless widget.

TabBar Class:

```
class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final GetxTab getxTab = Get.put(GetxTab());
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              controller: getxTab.tabController,
              tabs: getxTab.appTabs,
            ),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(controller: getxTab.tabController, children: [
            PageTabs1(),
            GetxExample(),
          ])),
    );
  }
}

class GetxTab extends GetxController with SingleGetTickerProviderMixin {
  late TabController tabController;
  final List<Tab> appTabs = <Tab>[
    Tab(
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.share,
        ),
        text: ("Bottom Sheet")),
    Tab(
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.share,
        ),
        text: ("Getx")),
  ];
  @override
  void onInit() {
    // TODO: implement onInit
    super.onInit();
    tabController = TabController(length: appTabs.length, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    // TODO: implement onClose
    super.onClose();
    tabController.dispose();
  }
}
```

First Page:

> Updated: Problem solved I just figure out I make a mistake adding GetMaterialApp, Scaffold
> both of my Parent and child class. Which conflicts one with another.
> So I just remove the child GetMaterialApp( home: Scaffold(

```
class PageNav3 extends StatelessWidget {
  const PageNav3({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Text(
          "Nav1",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Second Page:

> This page causes the Issue

```
class GetxExample extends StatelessWidget {
  GetxExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool value = true;
    return GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: GestureDetector(
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 45,
              child: My_Button(
                  ButtonText: "Change",
                  Backcolors: Colors.black,
                  FontColors: Colors.white,
                  padBot: 5,
                  padTop: 5,
                  padRight: 5,
                  padLeft: 5),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              value = !value;
             Get.bottomSheet(
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.blueGrey,
                  ),
                  child: Wrap(
                    children: [
                      AddListTittle(
                        Tittle: "Camera",
                        des: "Add Photo by clicking Camera",
                        iconss: Icons.camera,
                        Index: 0,
                        reqIndex: ImageSource.camera,
                      ),
                      AddListTittle(
                        Tittle: "Gallery",
                        des: "Add Photo from Gallery",
                        iconss: Icons.storage,
                        Index: 1,
                        reqIndex: ImageSource.gallery,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the scaffold keys to display snackbar, remove them and use the overlay support package, it offers a simpler implementation

Comment: No. I am not using Snackbar here

Comment: I just figure out I make a mistake adding GetMaterialApp, Scaffold both of my Parent and child class. Which conflicts one with another. So I just remove the child GetMaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(